# Problema de sintaxe ao compilar modelagem no Lingo

Tags: modelagem, otimização, matlab

Estou tentando resolver a modelagem de um exercício de programação linear no Lingo e toda vez que mando o software compilar o código recebo o código de erro:

**11. INVALID INPUT.  A SYNTAX ERROR HAS OCCURRED.**

porém, tudo que digitou parece estar correto e não consigo encontrar o erro. Gostaria de saber se o problema está na minha modelagem ou se preciso mudar alguma configuração para que tudo funcione corretamente.

A modelagem a qual me refiro é a seguinte:

```
MIN = x1 + x2 + x3

117/100*10^-5*x1 + 10^-5*x2 + 8*10^-6*x3 <= 1;
4*10^(6)*117/100*10^(-5)*x1 + 4*10^(6)*10^(-5)*x2 + 5*10^(6)*8*10^(-6)*x3 >= 25000000;
2*10^(6)*117/100*10^(-5)*x1 + 5*10^(6)*10^(-5)*x2 + 5*10^(6)*8*10^(-6)*x3 >= 20000000;
```

Algumas variações foram tentadas, como:

```
MIN x1 + x2 + x3
```

ou,

```
1.17 ao invés de usar 117/100
```

porém, nenhuma delas resolveu

Answer (score 0):

Olá,

Esta pergunta está tagged como `MATLAB`, porém usualemente matlab não é compilado (pelo menos do ponto de vista do usuário). Caso isto seja de matlab, vamos aos comentários:

MIN é uma outra variável ou uma funcão?

Você está querendo obter os valores das 3 equacões e comparar o resultado ou é um conjunto de equacões.

`x1`,`x2` e `x3` são variáveis simbólicas ou variáveis numéricas?

Aguardo comentários.